# Magento All Product Export dataflow error

Tags: magento

I am trying to export products in `Magento 1.9.1` using dataflow profiles, but it stops at `" Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data"`.

This is the error I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>
> Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Yesno::setAttribute()in
>   /home2/caferobo/domains/caferobot.ir/public_html/store1/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php
>   on line 389

Comment: Is this a Magento-usage or Magento-development related issue? I recommend you try the Magento-forum for better answers.

Comment: A Magento-usage problem. I will try Magento forums too. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours I found the solution.

look in your database table `eav_attribute` and search for attributes with `source_model = adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno`

Then replace it with a correct source model: `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean`

I found the solution [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Product-Export-Error/td-p/19438)

Hope this helps.